# Spring 5 JMS clientID=myapp.Topic was already set into another connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, jmstemplate

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.1 (w/ Spring 5) to kick off my server with Spring JmsTemplate (HornetQ) connections. Every ~10s an ERROR is logged,

```
2020-01-17 18:00:49,091 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] ERROR listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'a.Topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: clientID=myapp.Topic was already set into another connection
```

Did I accidentally create another client using the same id and compete for the connection/topic? Or something else I am not aware of.

Comment: sounds like you are reusing a the ClientID. Probably another application with the same ClientID. The name is strange though "myapp.Topic" - maybe you are confusing ClientID and Topic ?

Comment: It seems that I should have used `SingleConnectionFactory` instead of leaving to the default

Answer (score 1):

> Did I accidentally create another client using the same id and compete for the connection/topic?

Yes. According to the error message you're receiving you did.